# How close should my home be to a mob spawner?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found an above-ground spider mob spawner, and have turned it into an EXP grinder. I also have a self destruct switch in case it goes haywire, but using it will blow up my house.

Should I move my house?

Comment: In an effort to prevent this from being closed, can you provide more details? Perhaps a screenshot showing exactly how far your house is from the spawner?

Comment: "My house is next to a mob spawner which i use to grind EXP. Should i move my house?". Well, what exactly are you looking for? Our opinions? You want to know what the distance should be between the house and the spawn?

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely move your house; you don't want to lose all of your belongings if your mob traps goes haywire, and lose whatever progress you had farming.

So keep your mob spawn far away from your house if you plan on keeping a self-destruct button handy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether this is a single player game, or on a multiplayer server.

EXP grinders can cause lag when a lot of mobs are spawned.  So, you wouldn't want them to be constantly spawning when you're not killing them.

You won't need a self destruct mechanism.  Just follow the advice given by Retrosaur.